# Is there a way to try out sql commands like jsfiddle.net

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, postgresql

I'm really impress by jsfiddle.net where we get to try out html/css/js right in front of us.
Does anyone know of a similar set of screens for sql where you could get to try out commands and build tables in a similar 'virtual' environment.
Of course I would like it to support all the different flavors too - mySQL, SQLserver, DB2, Oracle, Postgres, etc.  And each of their various versions too please (yes I am smiling and really wishing here).

Comment: For each environment you could use a sample database and try things out this is what i do for pgsql using pgadmin, alternatively, why not write your own that is cross database?

Comment: I like jsfiddle but they really need to improve their capacity. Sometimes is a turtle!

Comment: @Icarus what are you talking about? It's pretty much as fast as I'd expect from a web application.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be one option that covers all the vendors, but you can't create your own tables etc.
http://www.sqlzoo.net/h.htm 
Another is http://sqlize.com/ which does let you create tables, though it is only mySQL.

Comment: Looks like sqlzoo isn't well maintained, maybe that'll change sometime after this comment

Answer (score 0):

You might try [ideone](http://ideone.com/). I haven't used it for SQL, but it's one of the listed options.

Comment: Doubtfully it will execute the query. There are dozens of SQL dialects.

Comment: yeah it's only set for sqlite, looks poor, but thx.  sqlzoo above looks great though!